# 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.IContentNegotiator' has not been registered

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I'm normally a Java developer. Today I decided I wanted to learn how to build a serverless web application in Azure using Microsoft's tools.

Since I'm a Mac user I installed the Mac version of Visual Studio.

Next, I created a new Functions solution and chose the template named "Http trigger with parameters".

I then pressed the Run button and saw that it opened a console window with a URL that I could use to access the service.

But when I hit that URL with curl from another window, I got this:

*System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Demo. Autofac: The requested service 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.IContentNegotiator' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.*

Being new to Microsoft tools in general, I have no idea what to do next. I'm also a little surprised that Microsoft would ship a tool in which running a default template with no changes would not work.

Frank

Comment: There is an open git-hub issue with [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1492) it seems

Comment: "I'm also a little surprised that Microsoft would ship a tool in which running a default template with no changes would not work."
Then you're *definitely* new to working with Microsoft stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the specific issue is with calling the extension method CreateResponse() on the request object. On the default template you should see something like this at the end of the run() method;

```
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Workaround is to instantiate and populate an HttpResponseMessage object explicitly.

Something like this works for me, after a normal CRUD insert operation;

```
// Save the entity and return a reference 
var blobReference = await SaveBlob(blob);
// Create an HttpContent object to package the reference
var blobRefContent = new ObjectContent<BlobReference>(blobReference, (MediaTypeFormatter)MediaTypeFormatter.GetDefaultValueForType(typeof(BlobReference)));
// Create a response containing the reference and the original request, as well as a successful return code
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created) { Content = blobRefContent, RequestMessage = req };
// Return the response
return response;
```